# Dropdown box in Widget of Android app

Tags: android, widget, dropdown

Hi I have developed an Android app. Now I am developing widget for this app. I have  a stupid query.

Can I use dropdown box(like`<select></select>` in html)  in widget?

Answer (score 0):

I think the view you're looking for is a [Spinner](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html).

Comment: Hi Juan, Yes I am looking for that but that in widget(Extension) not in app.

Comment: Any update? Please. I am talking about widget just like weather widget